# How do I switch between Xfce and unity?

Tags: unity, xfce, session, ubuntu-studio

How do I switch between Xfce and unity, after I installed Unity form the Software Center?
I've looked online and experimented and failed to find a the answer for this.
How do I switch from Xfce to Unity (on Ubuntu Studio)?
I saw some suggestions to switch by logging out and selecting one of the sessions installed. But all I have are Xfce session and ubuntustudio.

Found the Solution:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use other Desktop environment in Ubuntu-Studio and exchange whenever I want?, Xfce to Unity & Vise](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147380/can-i-use-other-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu-studio-and-exchange-whenever-i-wan)