# Can I run different versions of Ubuntu in a tab on my Chromebook

Tags: 14.04, unity, xfce

What I want to know is if I can run unity Ubuntu in a tab on my Chromebook.

Because recently I saw one tutorial on 'How-to-Geek' in which they used xfce and did not mention any other versions.

Comment: I think you are not using proper word to address your question. Unity and xfce are two different desktop environment. Two version means for example 14.04 and 15.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use other Desktop environment in Ubuntu-Studio and exchange whenever I want?, Xfce to Unity & Vise](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147380/can-i-use-other-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu-studio-and-exchange-whenever-i-wan)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

What do you mean by tab in 'run different versions of Ubuntu in a tab'.

It is apparent that your question is about installing two different desktop environment not different version. If I am right, your answer is YES.

How?

If you have unity, simply you can install xfce Desktop Enviroment by this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Then, in login page, you have option to choose to login to which environment.